# primefaces viewer in eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces

It's my first project with primefaces, I'm working with eclipse Kepler on a dynamic web project, I use maven for all dependencies. 
My project is a maven project and has spring nature(for other reasons).
I'm working also with  the last version of Jboss.

I created the following bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserInterfaceBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2143658709;

    @Autowired
    private transient DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService;

     private List<Aircraft> aircrafts; 

UserInterfaceBean(){

    aircrafts = dbDataManipulatorService.findAllAircrafts();
}

public List<Aircraft> getAircrafts(){

    return aircrafts;
}
```

}

and my xhtml file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>GLOBAL REPORT</title>
</h:head>
<body>
<p:dataTable var="aircraft" value="#{UserInterfaceBean.aircrafts}">
    <f:facet name="header"> List of Aircrafts</f:facet> 
    <p:columns value="#{userinterfaceBean.aircrafts}" var="column"
        columnIndexVar="colIndex">
        <f:facet name="header"> #{column}</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{userinterfaceBean.values[colIndex]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I can't get the correct view in the viewer, am I missing something, that I need to do or is there any error in my code? please give me a detailed response.

Comment: If you want to see the page preview , you should install Jboss tools from eclipse market.It's not the issue with kepler cause I am using it to check `XHTML` page preview.I see Couple of issues in your posted code. You shouldn't use `@Autowired` in JSF Managed Bean to inject spring Beans. You should use `@ManagedProperty` and you should enclose datatable inside a form.And Make `<body>` to `<h:body>` for consistency.

Comment: I already have Jboss tools installed and the preview doesn't work. for the @Autowired, I dont understand what do you mean, the autowired attribute is a service that I call to retrieve data from the database and I use it in the constructor of this bean. could you use some code for more details please.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/. In this example If you see annotation based example, he used `@component`along with `@managedBean` to make sure `@Autowired` works. But In your case, `UserInterfaceBean` is a pure JSF contolled managed bean, into which you are trying to `Autowire` spring Managed bean.

Answer (score 0):

Is your page displayed correctly in your browser when you build and deploy your project to the server?

Since you say that "can't get correct view in the viewer" I am guessing that you want to preview your xhtml page before you build and deploy. If that is the case then the core jsf tags can be previewed by eclipse but I don't think you can do that with Primefaces tags.

Also in order to get the values generated by the beans, for example: `#{UserInterfaceBean.aircrafts}` then your code must be build and deployed to the server.

Haven't worked with Netbeans but maybe you want to check [NetBeans 8 Loves PrimeFaces](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3021)

**EDIT**

In order to preview your `xhtml` page you need to have the the `Dynamic Web Module` facet and `JavaServer Faces facet` added to your project.

Then make sure that your xhtml is opened with `Web Page Editor`. So right click your xhtml file and do open with `Web Page Editor`.

Try using only core JSF tags as your first project since libraries like Primefaces wont work with the preview.

The beans are managed by and running at the server so in order to preview values that are generated by your beans then you need to have the code running at the server since the final xhtlm will be generated by the values that these beans provide.

These are the general rules so that you can work with eclipse.

**EDIT2**

Based on your provided xhtmml and and what you are trying to do and on this example (have altered it a bit) : [datatableDynamicColumns](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) here is some code that may help. For me it works both on **JBOSS EAP 6.2** and on **WildFly 8.0.0**. I am also using **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Kepler Service Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627 32 bit** with **JBOSS Tools (Kepler) 4.1.1 Final**

Pointing your browser to `http://localhost:8080/PrimeSimple/` and hitting refresh will bring you new results because of the random functions.

**Class Car**

```
package webapp;

public class Car 
{
    private String model;
    private int year;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String color;

    public Car(String model, int year, String manufacturer, String color) {
            this.model = model;
            this.year = year;
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
            this.color = color;
    }

    public String getModel() {
            return model;
    }
    public void setModel(String model) {
            this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
            return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
            this.year = year;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
            return manufacturer;
    }
    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getColor() {
            return color;
    }
    public void setColor(String color) {
            this.color = color;
    }
}
```

**Class Company**

```
package webapp;

import java.util.List;

public class Company 
{
    private String name;
    private List<Car> carList;
    //needed only for comparison
    private Integer carlistSize;

    public Company() {
    }

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Car> getCars() {
            return carList;
    }
    public void setCars(List<Car> carList) {
            this.carList = carList;
            carlistSize=carList.size();
    }

    public Integer getCarListSize() {
        return carlistSize;
    }

}
```

**Class PopulateCar **

```
package webapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class PopulateCar 
{
    private final static String[] colors;  
    private final static String[] manufacturers;  

    static {  
        colors = new String[10];  
        colors[0] = "Black";  
        colors[1] = "White";  
        colors[2] = "Green";  
        colors[3] = "Red";  
        colors[4] = "Blue";  
        colors[5] = "Orange";  
        colors[6] = "Silver";  
        colors[7] = "Yellow";  
        colors[8] = "Brown";  
        colors[9] = "Maroon";  

        manufacturers = new String[10];  
        manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";  
        manufacturers[1] = "BMW";  
        manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";  
        manufacturers[3] = "Audi";  
        manufacturers[4] = "Renault";  
        manufacturers[5] = "Opel";  
        manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";  
        manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";  
        manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";  
        manufacturers[9] = "Ford";  
    }

    public static List<Car> findAllCars(int size)
    {
        List<Car> carsSmall = new ArrayList<Car>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)  
            carsSmall.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));

        return carsSmall;
    }


    private static int getRandomYear() {  
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);  
    }  
    private static String getRandomColor() {  
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];  
    }  
    private static String getRandomManufacturer() {  
        return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];  
    }  
    private static String getRandomModel() {  
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);  
    }  
}
```

**Class PopulateCompany**

```
package webapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class PopulateCompany 
{
    private final static String[] compNames;  

    static {  
        compNames = new String[8];  
        compNames[0] = "Company1";  
        compNames[1] = "Company2";  
        compNames[2] = "Company3";  
        compNames[3] = "Company4";  
        compNames[4] = "Company5";  
        compNames[5] = "Company6";  
        compNames[6] = "Company7";  
        compNames[7] = "Company8";  
    }

    public static List<Company> findAllCompanies(int compSize)
    {
        List<Company> companyList = new ArrayList<Company>();

        for (int i=0;i<compSize;i++){
            Company company = new Company();
            company.setName(compNames[i]);

            int numOfCars = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 1) + 1));
            List<Car> carsOfCompany = PopulateCar.findAllCars(numOfCars);
            company.setCars(carsOfCompany);

            companyList.add(company);
        }


        Collections.sort(companyList, new Comparator<Company>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Company c1, Company c2) {
                return c2.getCarListSize().compareTo(c1.getCarListSize());
            }
        });

        return companyList;
    }
}
```

**Class TableBeanDynamic**

```
package webapp;

import java.io.Serializable;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.UUID;  

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;  

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TableBeanDynamic implements Serializable {  

    private List<String> columns;  
    private List<Car[]> dynamicCars;  
    private String columnName;  
    private List<Company> companies;  

    public TableBeanDynamic() {  

        int numOfCompanies = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((8 - 1) + 1));
        companies = PopulateCompany.findAllCompanies(numOfCompanies);

        createDynamicColumns();  
        populateDynamicCars();  
    }  

    private void createDynamicColumns() {  
        columns = new ArrayList<String>();  
        for(int i=0; i < companies.size(); i++) {  
            columns.add(companies.get(i).getName());  
        }  
    }

    private void populateDynamicCars() {  
        dynamicCars = new ArrayList<Car[]>();  

        for(int i=0; i < columns.size(); i++) 
        {  
            Car[] cars = new Car[companies.get(i).getCars().size()];  

            for(int j=0; j < cars.length; j++) {  
                cars[j] = new Car(  companies.get(i).getCars().get(j).getModel(), 
                                    companies.get(i).getCars().get(j).getYear(),
                                    companies.get(i).getCars().get(j).getManufacturer(),
                                    companies.get(i).getCars().get(j).getColor());  
            }  

            dynamicCars.add(cars);  
        }  
    }  



    public List<String> getColumns() {  
        return columns;  
    }  

    public List<Car[]> getDynamicCars() {  
        return dynamicCars;  
    }  

    public String getColumnName() {  
        return columnName;  
    }  

    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {  
        this.columnName = columnName;  
    }  
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"       
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>PrimeFaces DynamicColumnTable Example</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <!-- <h:form>  
           <p:dataTable var="cars" value="#{tableBeanDynamic.dynamicCars}" id="carsTable">  
                <p:columns value="#{tableBeanDynamic.columns}"  var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">  

                  <f:facet name="header">  
                        <p:outputPanel>  
                            #{column}  
                        </p:outputPanel>  
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="#{cars[colIndex].model}" /><br />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{cars[colIndex].year}" /> <br />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{cars[colIndex].color}" style="color:#{cars[colIndex].color}"/>  
                </p:columns>  
            </p:dataTable> 
        </h:form> --> 

        <h:form>
            <!-- dynamicCars list is ordered. So I get the first Car[] element from the list which has the maximum number 
            of elements so that p:dataTable will generate that many rows as the number of elements in the first Car[] of
            the list -->      
           <p:dataTable var="cars" value="#{tableBeanDynamic.dynamicCars.get(0)}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" id="carsTable">  
                <p:columns value="#{tableBeanDynamic.columns}"  var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">  

                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <p:outputPanel>  
                            #{column}  
                        </p:outputPanel>  
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBeanDynamic.dynamicCars[colIndex][rowIndex].model}" /><br />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBeanDynamic.dynamicCars[colIndex][rowIndex].year}" /> <br />  
                    <h:outputText value="#{tableBeanDynamic.dynamicCars[colIndex][rowIndex].color}" style="color:#{tableBeanDynamic.dynamicCars[colIndex][rowIndex].color}"/>  
                </p:columns>  
            </p:dataTable> 
        </h:form> 

    </h:body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>so.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>PrimeSimple</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <description>Simple Primefaces Example</description>


        <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following
            message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- JBoss dependency versions -->
        <version.jboss.maven.plugin>7.4.Final</version.jboss.maven.plugin>

        <!-- Define the version of the JBoss BOMs we want to import to specify
            tested stacks. -->
        <version.jboss.bom>1.0.7.Final</version.jboss.bom>
        <!-- Alternatively, comment out the above line, and un-comment the line
            below to use version 1.0.4.Final-redhat-4 which is a release certified to
            work with JBoss EAP 6. It requires you have access to the JBoss EAP 6
            maven repository. -->
        <!-- <version.jboss.bom>1.0.4.Final-redhat-4</version.jboss.bom>> -->

        <!-- other plugin versions -->
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.10</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE 6 APIs including a Bill
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection)
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools stack (you can
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE 6 APIs, with some extras tools
                for your project, such as Arquillian for testing) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- First declare the APIs we depend on and need for compilation. All
            of them are provided by JBoss AS 7 -->

        <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope
            as the API is included in JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Import the EJB API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Import the JSF API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
            JBoss AS 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name
            given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- The JBoss AS plugin deploys your war to a local JBoss AS container -->
            <!-- To use, run: mvn package jboss-as:deploy -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- The default profile skips all tests, though you can tune it to run
                just unit tests based on a custom pattern -->
            <!-- Seperate profiles are provided for running all tests, including Arquillian
                tests that execute in the specified container -->
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Check to see if that works after build and deploy, not preview, as we have discussed it will not work. If it works then you need to see how to connect with your DB and create the actual query that return ,in the examples case, a list of Companies that each contain a list of cars.

**EDIT** there is an error in the view with the previous `xhtml` file: the number of rows would always be the same as the number of columns and thus not all results would be shown. I am leaving the old solution in comments for others to see.

Comment: Yeh, I want to work on the preview before deploy, but it doesn't work. more over it doesn't work on any browser(neither firefox nor safari nor chrome) despite I added the project to tomcat. do you think there is another problem? for the IDE i prefer working with eclipse, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Don't have eclipse at my hands right now in order to check your code. If I do I will let you know.

Comment: all the things you talked about were already done before I post my request. but it still doesn't work

Comment: A bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish with your code. Are you trying to add the number of columns dynamically?

Comment: yeh, that's my aim. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: A bit more complex. Have you tried the simpler examples? Do they work for you? I am asking since you say that is your first project with primefaces.

Comment: yeh I tried hello world example of MKyong and it worked on the browser but not the preview. but I'm working on a project where I have for example a classroom where there is lot of school bags(represented as a list of bags) that contains some books (represented by a list of books for each school bag) and the view I want to get is a table where columns represent the bags and the rows represent the books, and in different bags there is a different number of books but similar themes(mathematics, science, and so on). can you help me with that what should I use and how can implement that, please.

Comment: thanks for your efforts,but even your project didn't work. do you have any idea about the source of problem

Comment: here is the war and project http://bit.ly/NdOqyC try it (on Jboss EAP or wildlfy) and let me know

Comment: Problem solved, web.xml file wasn't in the right place, thanks a lot Zlinks

Comment: Has it helped you at all?